# Configuration to handle Dead-letter queue

Tags: java, configuration, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, dead-letter

I have a project that uses Spring Cloud Streams - RabbitMQ to exchange messages within micro-services. One thing that is critical for my project is that I must not lose any message.

In order to minimize failures, I planned the following:

- Use the default retry method for messages in queue
- Configure dead-letter queue to put messages again on queue after some time
- To avoid an infinite loop, allow only a few times (let's say, 5) a message could be republished from dead-letter queue to regular messaging queue.

The first two items I believe I could make it using the configuration below:

```
#dlx/dlq setup - retry dead letter 5 minutes later (300000ms later)
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.republish-to-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-ttl=300000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-dead-letter-exchange=

#input
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myInput.destination=my-queue
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myInput.group=my-group
```

However, I could not find [searching on this reference guide](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/multi/multi__configuration_options.html#rabbit-binder-properties) how to do what I want (mostly, how to configure a maximum number of republish from dead-letter queue). I'm not completely sure I'm on the right path - maybe I should manually create a second queue and code what I want, and leave dead-letter only to messages that completely failed (which I must check regularly and handle manually, since my system should not lose any messages)...

I'm new to these frameworks, and I would like your help to configure mine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This documentation for the rabbit binder](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#rabbit-dlq-processing) shows how to publish a dead-letter to some parking-lot queue after some number of retries have failed.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReRouteDlqApplication {

    private static final String ORIGINAL_QUEUE = "so8400in.so8400";

    private static final String DLQ = ORIGINAL_QUEUE + ".dlq";

    private static final String PARKING_LOT = ORIGINAL_QUEUE + ".parkingLot";

    private static final String X_RETRIES_HEADER = "x-retries";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ReRouteDlqApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hit enter to terminate");
        System.in.read();
        context.close();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @RabbitListener(queues = DLQ)
    public void rePublish(Message failedMessage) {
        Integer retriesHeader = (Integer) failedMessage.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().get(X_RETRIES_HEADER);
        if (retriesHeader == null) {
            retriesHeader = Integer.valueOf(0);
        }
        if (retriesHeader < 3) {
            failedMessage.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().put(X_RETRIES_HEADER, retriesHeader + 1);
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(ORIGINAL_QUEUE, failedMessage);
        }
        else {
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(PARKING_LOT, failedMessage);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue parkingLot() {
        return new Queue(PARKING_LOT);
    }

}
```

The second example shows how to use the delayed exchange plugin to delay between retries.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReRouteDlqApplication {

    private static final String ORIGINAL_QUEUE = "so8400in.so8400";

    private static final String DLQ = ORIGINAL_QUEUE + ".dlq";

    private static final String PARKING_LOT = ORIGINAL_QUEUE + ".parkingLot";

    private static final String X_RETRIES_HEADER = "x-retries";

    private static final String DELAY_EXCHANGE = "dlqReRouter";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ReRouteDlqApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hit enter to terminate");
        System.in.read();
        context.close();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @RabbitListener(queues = DLQ)
    public void rePublish(Message failedMessage) {
        Map<String, Object> headers = failedMessage.getMessageProperties().getHeaders();
        Integer retriesHeader = (Integer) headers.get(X_RETRIES_HEADER);
        if (retriesHeader == null) {
            retriesHeader = Integer.valueOf(0);
        }
        if (retriesHeader < 3) {
            headers.put(X_RETRIES_HEADER, retriesHeader + 1);
            headers.put("x-delay", 5000 * retriesHeader);
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(DELAY_EXCHANGE, ORIGINAL_QUEUE, failedMessage);
        }
        else {
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(PARKING_LOT, failedMessage);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange delayExchange() {
        DirectExchange exchange = new DirectExchange(DELAY_EXCHANGE);
        exchange.setDelayed(true);
        return exchange;
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindOriginalToDelay() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(new Queue(ORIGINAL_QUEUE)).to(delayExchange()).with(ORIGINAL_QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue parkingLot() {
        return new Queue(PARKING_LOT);
    }

}
```